# vue3/typescript + d3.js: argument of type ComputeRef<number[]> is not assigned to iterable<number>

Tags: typescript, vuejs3

Copied from example here: https://medium.com/@lambrospd/5-simple-rules-to-data-visualization-with-vue-js-and-d3-js-f6b2bd6a1d40

I tried to create a typescript/v3 version of the example and below is my code

```
<script lang="ts">
import { ref, defineComponent, computed, toRef } from "vue";
import * as d3 from 'd3';

export default defineComponent({
  name: "StandardMetric",
   props: {
   data: {
      required: true,
      type: Array,
    },
    width: {
      default: 500,
      type: Number,
    },
    height: {
      height: 270,
      type: Number,
    }

   },
   setup: function (props, {attrs, slots, emit}){

      const padding = ref(60);

      const rangeY = computed(() => {
        const defaultHeight = toRef(props, 'height').value;
        const height: Number = defaultHeight?defaultHeight:270 - padding.value;
        const result = [0, height];
        return result;
      });
      
      const rangeX = computed(() => {
        const defaultWidth: Number = toRef(props, 'width').value;
        const width: Number = defaultWidth?defaultWidth:500 - padding.value;
        return [0, width];
      });

      
      const path = computed(()=> {
      // const x = d3.scaleLinear().range(rangeX);
      // v1 error
      // const x = d3.scaleLinear().range(rangeX.value);
      // v2 error

      const x = d3.scaleLinear().range([0, 500]);
      const y = d3.scaleLinear().range(rangeY.value);
      d3.axisLeft().scale(x);
      d3.axisTop().scale(y);
      x.domain(d3.extent(this.data, (d, i) => i));
      y.domain([0, d3.max(this.data, d => d)]);
      return d3.line()
        .x((d, i) => x(i))
        .y(d => y(d));
     }),
```

Then in the computed function: path and in the first statement the error pop up
if i use the v1 statement, the error is:

> argument of type ComputeRef<number[]> is not assignable to iterable

If I use the v2 statement, the error is:

> argument of type number[] is not assignable to iterable

But if i hard code it to [0,500] it passed without error message.
I wonder what's the proper way to write the statement. Can you please provide some help?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't try it atm but I think problem might be in your use of `Number`

[TS docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html)

> The type names `String`, `Number`, and `Boolean` (starting with capital letters) are legal, but refer to some special built-in types that will very rarely appear in your code. Always use `string`, `number`, or `boolean` for types.

Uppercase variants are used in `props` definition is OK - this is required by Vue and has nothing to do with TS....

Also both `rangeY` and `rangeX` do not require any type annotations as TS perfectly capable to infer the types....

**EDIT**

I was right. And of course some more changes were required to make TS happy. Bellow is the working component (Vue 3.0.11, d3 6.6.2, '@types/d3': 6.3.0, typescript: 4.1.5)

```js
<template>
  <svg
    class="line-chart"
    :viewBox="`0 0 ${width} ${height}`"
  >
    <g >
      <path
        class="line-chart__line"
        :d="path"
      />
    </g>
  </svg>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { ref, defineComponent, computed, PropType } from "vue";
import * as d3 from 'd3';

export default defineComponent({
  name: "LineChart",
  props: {
    data: {
      required: true,
      type: Array as PropType<number[]>,
    },
    width: {
      type: Number,
      default: 500,      
    },
    height: {
      type: Number,
      default: 270,      
    }
  },
  setup: function (props){

      const padding = ref(20);

      const rangeY = computed(() => {
        const defaultHeight = props.height;
        const height = defaultHeight ? defaultHeight : 270 - padding.value;        
        return [0, height];
      });
      
      const rangeX = computed(() => {
        const defaultWidth = props.width;
        const width = defaultWidth ? defaultWidth : 500 - padding.value;
        return [0, width];
      });
      
      const path = computed(()=> {
        const x = d3.scaleLinear().domain([0, props.data.length]).range(rangeX.value);
        const y = d3.scaleLinear().domain([0, d3.max(props.data) as number]).range(rangeY.value);
        const axisX = d3.axisLeft(y);
        const axisY = d3.axisBottom(x);
        const line = d3.line()
          .x((d) => x(d[1]))
          .y(d => y(d[0]));
        
        return line(props.data.map((value, index) => [value, index]));
      })

    return {
      path
    }      
  }
});
</script>

<style lang="sass">
.line-chart
  margin: 25px
  &__line
    fill: none
    stroke: #76BF8A
    stroke-width: 3px
</style>
```

Comment: Yes you are right :) thanks for the help. I should have learnt more typescritp basic! I can't find the button to mark this as an answer for some reason